# all values not displaying from SQL data table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display all my data from MySQL to PHP like the following, but only 1 data is being displayed

```
<div class="content">
<div class="animated fadeIn">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">
<strong class="card-title">Data Table</strong>
  </div>
<div class="card-body">

<?php

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registers";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $test= $row['id'];
        }
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
// Close connection
?>
<table id="bootstrap-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
    <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $test; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $name?></td>
  <td><?php echo $email?></td>
  <td><?php echo $company?></td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

now the problem is, only one data is being displayed in the table, how can I display all data with my same code? can anyone please tell?

Comment: You set `$test` multiple times, but you only echo it once.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but how can i display multiple times without echoing it for each values

Comment: You can echo the table rows inside the `while` loop where you retrieve the data from the database.

Comment: if you want to display it multiple times then you need to echo it multiple times.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but when i am echoing it in the while loop all my js for table is not working

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript?

Comment: for that, you have to show the JS too. there may be error in your js selectors.

Comment: Can I suggest that you go and read a couple of tutorials from the web to get you started on the concept of processing the result of a query. Maybe start with the [examples in the PHP Manual](https://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

  // Attempt select query execution
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM registers";
  $test=array();
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                      array_push($test,$row);
                }
           // Free result set
             mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else{
               echo "No records matching your query were found.";
        }
     } else{
         echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
     }
```

In your view part, you have add `foreach` to print all values:

```
<?php 
foreach($test as $record){?>
 <tr>
    <td><?php echo $test['id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $test['name'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $test['email'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $test['company']?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: _Small Point_ If you are only pushing one thing into the array its quicker to do `$test[] = $row;` instead of `array_push()` as you dont have the overhead of calling a function

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code, you never seem to set the $name, $email and $company variables, and you have looped through an array and set your HTML after the loop, so you will only ever display one result.

Edit coming soon.

```
<table id="bootstrap-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM registers";

if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $test= $row['id'];

            <tr>
                <td><?=$row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['email']; ?></td>
                <td><?=$row['company']; ?></td>
            </tr>

        }

        mysqli_free_result($result);

    } else {

        echo "No records matching your query were found.";

    }

} else {

    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);

}

?>
</table>
```